# "bevor" mit realen und irrealen Situationen

Tags: conjunction, subjunctive

Dies kam heute in den Nachrichten:

> "Der Junge wurde gerettet, bevor er von den Wassermassen fortgerissen wurde."

Nun wurde der Junge aber - eben aufgrund der Rettung - eben *nicht* fortgerissen. Nach meinem Empfinden sollte dies durch den Konjunktiv o.ä. ausgedrückt werden. Aber andererseits hört sich "bevor er fortgerissen worden wäre" für meine Ohren auch nicht schön an. Ist solch eine Unterscheidung real/irreal mit bevor überhaupt üblich?

Offenbar wird im Alltag die Unterscheidung entweder ganz vergessen oder anders zum Ausdruck gebracht, so dass man die tragischere Variante zu oben vielleicht eher

> "Der Junge wurde zunächst gerettet, bevor er dann am Ende leider doch noch von den Wassermassen fortgerissen wurde"

formulieren würde ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ich würde sagen, die gängige Version ist:

> ..., bevor er von den Wassermassen fortgerissen werden konnte.

Der Originalsatz ist wahrscheinlich auf schlichte Schlamperei (oder Zeitdruck) zurückzuführen.

Comment: Scheint wohl so zu sein. Ich wollte aber lieber nachfragen, ob etwas dahinter steckt - schließlich ist "bevor" ja auch für den kreativen Umgang mit Verneinungen bekannt: "Bevor du nicht den Spinat aufgegessen hast, gibt es keinen Pudding!" :)

Comment: Haha... das Pudding Beispiel ist wirklich komisch wenn man drüber nachdenkt :)

Comment: Ja, aber durchaus verbreiteter Sprachgebrauch ...